# Shapefile/vector layer not appearing in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, vector, qgis-2, import

I have a shapefile (calling it 'new.shp' for discussion's sake) that won't show up with other layers.

If a fresh file is started and I bring in 'new.shp', it will appear, but any other layers imported after does not. On the flip side, if other layers are imported first, the other layers appear, but 'new.shp' will not show up.

That's not too much detail to troubleshoot from, but I was hoping someone might be able to suggest what the issue might be?

Other notes:

- I looked into the CRS for 'new.shp' which says (EPSG:4326, WGS 84); The other layers are also set to this.
- Using QGIS 2.10.1 on Windows 7

Comment: What result do you get for that layer using `Vector | Geometry Tools | Check Geometry Validity`?

Comment: Do you have .shx .prj and .dbf along the .shp as well? What extent does QGIS report with rightclick on the layer -> Properties, Metadata tab?

Comment: When you open new.shp first, what coordinates do you see in the status bar? Are they plausible lat/lon values, that is lat values in the range -90 to 90, for the area you are working in?

Comment: Really appreciate the responses--

(The 'check geometry validity' process is stalled at 52%. It's a large file, so it could take some time.)

Comment: The .shx, .prj and .dbf are with the .shp. In terms of the extent of metadata, it's reported:
In layer spatial reference system units: xMin, yMin 10580040.99, -1231313.95 : xMax, yMax 15699360.899,677736.15
Layer spatial reference System: +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
--Looking at the metadata and status bar, it seems the lat/lon are not plausible. 

Is there a way to adjust the lat/lon?

Comment: What location does the data represent? Like state, county, country, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If there is a .prj file, look into that with a text editor for projection information. Otherwise you have to ask the data creator.

It is definitely something projected in meters or foot. That is the reason you will not see it in a 180/90-degree view of the world, as defined by the WGS84 EPSG:4326 CRS.

To sanitize the project, remove the layer. Under `Settings -> Options, CRS tab, CRS for new layers`, select `Prompt for CRS`, and add the layer again. That should wipe away most CRS mistakes.

Comment: According to the .prj file, the projection is in fact in meters. Would it be possible to change this?

Comment: It is safer to remove and re-add the layer, as you can see in my extended answer. If there is a .qpj file created, remove that before. If QGIS still asks for a CRS, remember the text after `PROJCS` in the .prj file and search for it in the CRS list.

Comment: ... and please promise to **NEVER** use `Set CRS for Layer` again unless you are told to do so.

Comment: _please promise to **NEVER** use `Set CRS for Layer` again unless you are told to do so_ - Maybe this should be included as a start-up tip :)

Comment: After changing the settings and looking at the text after PROJCS in the .prj file to search from the CRS, all is working now!

Comment: You are the best