# Problem with CSV to point shapefile

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, point, csv, latitude-longitude

Using Qgis 2.18, I am trying to load a CSV file with a column for latitude and one for longitude. The points in the CSV are for England. When I load the file, the shapefile is created, but there is a distortion (please have a look at the image)

[image]

I changed the CRS to the British Nation Grid, but the distortion still exists. Moreover when I load a British Grid polygon shapefile it is distorted as well (while when I load it in another project is fine) and at the same time points are not lying on the polygons (they are lost). "On the fly" is automatically enabled. [image: At this screenshot you can she that when both files are at the same crs they don't lye each other. Points keep the distortion, their scale changes and they move where the purple dot is]

Do you have any idea?

Comment: looks ok to me - change the map projection to epsg:27700 if you want it to be taller and thinner

Comment: Hi! Thanks. It does not work. I updated my post in order to make things clearer. Please have a look.

Comment: did you set the projection of the point layer - should be 4326?

Comment: I did it. Both layers have the British National Grid 27700. I tried it with both layers at 4326 but nothing.

Comment: but your points are 4326 while the county map is 27700 - otherwise they won't line up

Comment: What is the coordinate system of the coordinates in your csv (not the CRS of the layer after importation)

Comment: @iant at the 2nd pic, both are in 27700.

Comment: @JGH How can I check this?

Comment: It should be in the metadata or indicated by the provider.. Do they look like lat-long or meters?

Comment: they look like lat-lon(an example is: 49.91332584 -6.298449)

Comment: Metadata are empty. A colleague shared the file. I will ask him for the source in order to check the original file

Comment: see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/162128/shapefile-vector-layer-not-appearing-in-qgis

Comment: thank you both. It didn't work. I asked for the metadata. I will be back to you when I will have them. Many thanks

Comment: You need to reset the data's (layer's?) coordinate system to 4326 (WGS 84, a geographic coordinate reference system). Then the project-on-the-fly will work.Currently the software thinks the lat/lon values are actually projected British National Grid coords, which is why the data shows up near the 0,0 point of BNG.